# query to fetch data from a table with restriction on list field mapped as many to many relationship

Tags: sql, database, hibernate, spring-mvc, detachedcriteria

Kindly help me with hibernate template or detached criteria query, to fetch data from a table Clause. It has a set of Department table (Many to Many relationship). Now, i need list of only those clauses which are associated with any of the department list- List deptIdList (This is the input parameter). I could get the desired result using SQL native query but i want to achieve the result using hql or detached criteria query.

```
public class Clause {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "CLAUSE_ID")
  private Long clauseId;

  @Column(name = "REG_REFERENCE")
  private String regulatoryReference;

  @Column(name = "REG_REQ")
  private String regulatoryRequirement;

  @Column(name = "REQ_IMP_RATING")
  private String reqImpactRating;

  @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(name = "EWMS_CLAUSE_DEPT", 
     joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "CLAUSE_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, 
     inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "DEPT_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) }
  )
  private Set<Department> departmentListForClause;

  @Column(name = "CLAUSE_KEY_ACT")
  private String keyActivity;

  @Column(name = "CLAUSE_TOPIC")
  private String clauseTopic;

  @Column(name = "CLAUSE_KEY_WORDS")
  private String clauseKeywords;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "REG_ID")
  private RegulationDetails regulation;

  //getter setter methods
}

public class Department {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "DEPT_ID")
  private Long departmentId;

  @Column(name = "DEPT_NAME")
  private String departmentName;

  @Column(name = "TIER1_ID")
  private String tierId;

  @ManyToMany(/*fetch = FetchType.LAZY,*/ mappedBy = "regulatoryDepartments")
  private Set<RegulationDetails> regulationListForDepartment;

  @ManyToMany(/*fetch = FetchType.LAZY, */mappedBy = "departmentListForClause")
  private Set<Clause> clauseListForDepartment;

  //getter setter methods
}
```